# How to define different stop/restart signals with upstart

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, upstart, unicorn

I am starting to convert all of our systems to using upstart to manage our various application processes. One thing that I am constantly missing is the ability to send a different signal to the process on `stop` or `restart` events.

For instance, we run our web processes with [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/). Unicorn has a great signal handling API. When I want to gracefully reload the process I send the master pid a USR2 signal. To shut them down gracefully I send a QUIT command. TERM (upstart's default stop signal) constitutes an immediate shutdown.

Another example is using [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque). To gracefully shut down a worker I send it the QUIT signal. The TERM signal again causes immediate shutdown, whether the worker's child is forked or not.

Does upstart support custom signals? I can't seem to find it anywhere, which worries me that I'm using the "wrong tool for the job".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 comes with upstart version 0.6.6 which has the [`kill signal` and `kill timeout`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#kill-signal) parameters which would configure relevant signal and timeout values. The "reload" signal is hardcoded to `SIGHUP`.

Newer versions of `upstart` introduce the [`reload signal` parameter](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#reload-signal) - see other answers to this question for further detail.

Comment: Good to know, not sure why the reload signal is hardcoded but I guess I'll have to live with it for the time being.

Comment: According to diclophis' answer below, this is now possible via `reload signal SIGUSR2`, but requires upstart v 1.10.0.

Answer (score 6):

As of upstart v1.10.0 you can define a "reload signal".

https://launchpad.net/upstart/1.x/1.10.0

This version is available on ubuntu as of v13.10 ... I used these instructions to upgrade my ec2 instance:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/302762/upgrading-13-04-to-13-10

I use rails+puma and do graceful reloads with this directive in my /etc/init/app-1.conf file:

```
reload signal SIGUSR2
```